# A question on translation invariance of functions

Tags: intuition, invariance, homogeneous-spaces

As I understand it, a given function, $f$ (sticking to one dimension for simplicity) is said to be *translationally invariant* if $$f(x+a)=f(x)$$ for any arbitrary constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$. 
This condition then implies that $f$ cannot have any functional dependence on position $x$, since it must hold for any value $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Furthermore, generalising slightly, a so-called *two-point* function (using "physics lingo"), $g$ is said to be *translationally invariant* if $$g(x+a, y+a)=g(x,y)$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is any arbitrary constant.
For this condition to hold for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, it must be the case that $g$ can (at most) only be dependent on the relative separation $x-y$, such that $g(x,y)\equiv g(x-y)$.

My question is, can one show in a more mathematically rigorous way (as opposed to the heuristic arguments that I have given) why $f(x+a)=f(a)\Rightarrow f=\text{constant}$, and $g(x+a,y+a)=g(x,y)\Rightarrow g\equiv g(x-y)$?

Comment: "$f(x+a)=f(x)$ for some constant $a$" only implies that $f$ is periodic. You need $f(x+a)=f(x)$ for *all* $a$ to obtain that $f$ is constant.

Comment: @Rahul         Yes, you're right, I should've clarified that $a$ is arbitrary. I'll update it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Monodimensional case**

We suppose that $$f(x+a) = f(x) ~\forall a, x.$$
Then it is also true that:
$$f(a+x) = f(a) ~\forall a, x.$$

We can conclude that $f(x) = f(a) ~\forall a, x$, and hence $f(x)$ is constant.

**Bidimensional case**

We suppose that $$g(x,y) = g(x+a, y+a) ~\forall a, x, y.$$

Let's pose $z = y+a$, and hence $a = -y+z$. Then:

$$g(x,y) = g(x-y+z, z) = g(x-y, 0).$$

Then, $g(x,y)$ is function of $x-y$ only.

Alternatively, this can be proven as follows:

$$g(x,y) = g(x-y,y-y) = g(x-y,0).$$

Comment: How can one set $a$ equal to a variable though when it's simply a parameter? Is the point that, since $a$ is arbitrary, for each $(x,y)$ we can translate the system by that particular value of $y$, e.g. if we consider a particular point $(x,y)=(x_{1},y_{1})$, then we can choose $a=-y_{1}$ (since $a$ is an arbitrary constant), such that $g(x_{1}+a,y_{1}+a)=g(x_{1}-y_{1},0)\equiv g(x_{1}-y_{1})$?! Also, what about the case of a "one-point" function, $f(x+a)=f(x)$, how does one show that $=\text{constant}$? Are the heuristic arguments that I gave in my original post correct?

Comment: @user35305 for the "one-point" case see again my answer ("Monodimensional case"). For the "two-points" case, $a$, $x$, $z$, $y$ and whatever are just any number you wish. Anyway, if you don't like this, look at the alternative proof at the end of the answer.

Comment: @user35305 Briefly... $f(x+a) = f(x) = f(a) ~\forall a,x \Rightarrow f(x) $ is constant. $g(x,y) = g(x-y,y-y) = g(x-y,0) ~\forall x, y$.

Comment: Ah ok, so is the point that $a$ is arbitrary, and so, whatever values for $x$ and $y$ we choose, we are always free to set $a=-y$ (considering the bidimensional case)?! What confuses me in the monodimensinal case is that I have always thought of $x$ as a variable and $a$ as a parameter, i.e. at each point $x$ we are free to shift by a constant $a$ such that the value of the function remains constant.

Comment: Try to think it in this way: fix $x = 1$ and $a = 2$. Then: $$f(1+2) = f(1) = f(2).$$ This is true for any choice of $x$ and $a$.

Comment: So, essentially, whatever value of $x$ one chooses, one is free to then choose any value of $a$ one wishes?! Heuristically, is it correct to say that, in the monodimensinal case, that the only way that $f(x+a)=f(x)$ can hold true for *any* value of $x$ *and any* value of $a$ that we choose, is if $f$ is in fact *independent* of $x$?! ...

Comment: Definitely, yes, $f$ is independent of $x$

Comment: ... In the bidimensional case, is an analogous argument true, i.e. the only way that $g(x+a,y+a)=g(x,y)$ can hold true for *any* values of $x$ and $y$, *and any* value of $a$ that we choose, is if, in actual fact, $g$ is only dependent on the relative difference $x-y$?! What confused me before, was that in some notes that I've read, the author refers to $a$ as a *constant* shift, but is the point that this constant shift, $a$ can be arbitrarily chosen at each point?

Comment: This is a linguistic problem. Mathematically, $$g(x+a,y+a) = g(x,y) ~\forall a, x, y$$ is different from $$g(x+a, y+a) = g(x,y) ~\forall x, y, ~\text{and $a$ fixed}$$...

Comment: For example $g(x,y) = \sin(x-y)$ satisfies the first (and the second), while $g(x,y) = \sin(x)\sin(y)$ satisfies **only** the second.

Comment: So, in the case of translational invariance, is it the former condition, i.e. $$g(x+a,y+a)=g(x,y)\quad\forall\; a,x,y$$ and similarly $$f(x+a)=f(x)\quad\forall\; a,x$$ I think it's the distinction that some authors make about $x$ and $y$ being variables and $a$ being a parameter is what has confused me. Is the point that $x$ and $y$ are the variables that the function $g$ is dependent on, and $a$ is an arbitrary parameter that we can choose independently of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @user35305 exactly!!!

Comment: Ok great, thanks for all your help! Just one last thing, are the heuristic arguments that I gave (for why $f$ must be independent of $x$ and why $g$ must be dependent only on the difference $x-y$) correct at all?

Comment: @user35305 yes, I guess they are correct

Comment: Also, sorry to reiterate, but just to check, is what I said at the end of the previous comment, *"I think it's the distinction that some authors make about $x$ and $y$ being variables and $a$ being a parameter is what has confused me. Is the point that $x$ and $y$ are the variables that the function $g$ is dependent on, and $a$ is an arbitrary parameter that we can choose independently of $x$ and $y$?"*, correct?!

Comment: @user35305 no problem, you are welcome! It is correct :D

Comment: @the_candyman in general, shouldn't it be $f(x+ka,y+kb) = f(x,y), \forall k,x,y \text{ and } a,b \text{ fixed?}$ That is, to have $b=a$ we'd have to rescale $x$ or $y$.