# Why can the average/midpoint of two numbers be described as the sum of the numbers divided by two?

Tags: statistics, intuition, average, visualization

Say I have two numbers, A and B. The "average" or the midpoint of the two numbers is given by $$\frac{A+B}{2}$$ 
My question is, why does this formula work?

Intuitively, I can derive the equation as follows. The "midpoint" of the two numbers can be given by:
$$A+\frac{B-A}{2}$$
$$=\frac{2A}{2}+\frac{B-A}{2}$$
$$=\frac{A+B}{2}$$
But why? Why is it when you add two numbers and divided it by two you get its "midpoint"? I can't seem to find a way to intuitively visualize this. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have this visualization:

$\mathtt{|----|------+------|----|}\\
O\hphantom{----}A\hphantom{------}\ \ I\hphantom{------}\ \ \,B\hphantom{---}A+B$

- $I$ is the midpoint of $[A,B]$
- but $\operatorname{dist}(O,A)=\operatorname{dist}(B,A+B)=a$

Thus $I$ is also the midpoint of $[O,A+B]$.

And since you agree it is $I=O+\dfrac{(A+B)-O}2$ and that $O$ can be identified to the zero of point addition, then $I=\dfrac{A+B}{2}$.

Comment: Is there a general term that describes operations where the result is the same when you increase each operand by the same amount? That is op(A,B) = op(A+C, B+C). This is obvious for subtraction, but I am wondering if there other such operations that would warrant a name for this property.

Comment: The property is called "Invariance by translation". You can check this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1919521/399263, for a 2D function to verify this then $f(x,y)=\phi(x-y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have two measuring cups.  One has $A$ ounces of water and the other has $B$ ounces.   Also suppose that $B$ is bigger than $A$ and I want the same amount of liquid in each cup.

So I can pour some of the $B$ cup into the $A$ cup until the amounts are equal.  How much is in each cup?  I have a total of $A+B$ ounces and they are equally divided into 2 cups.  So each cup has $(A+B)/2$ ounces.